# How work out the length of this side?

Tags: geometry

[image: 5x]

This is probably so basic, but I just cannot see it.  If you do not know that the left side is $5x$ and are only given $3x$ and $4x$, how do you deduce $5x$?

Comment: Could you tell as precisely what we are given?  And what we are trying to figure.  I'd interpret the drawing as saying we are *given* the side if 5x (from which I'd conclude the triangle is right and I'd be able to calculate the bold area).  If we *don't* know the side is 5x and we are given neither the bold area or that the triangle is right we can't conclude anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can deduce that $AC=5x$ only if $\angle ABC=90°$ because in this case the triple $3x,4x,5x$ is a [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple).

Answer (score 1):

As Emilio Novati implies, **all** right triangles, with given angle $\theta$, are "similar triangles".  So since the legs have ratio $\frac{3x}{4x}$, the hypotenuse must be a multiple of the hypotenuse with legs of length 3 and 4 which is, of course, 5.  The hypotenuse must have length 5x.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure we are not *given* that the dotted side if 5x?  What actually is the exercise we are supposed to solve?

We can conclude that if the triangle is right then the side is 5x.  And if we are given that the side if 5x we can conclude the triangle is right.

But if we are given neither we can't conclude either.

If we knew the length of the bold arrow we could use trigonometry to figure out the angle and third side.  And given that the triangle is right or the third side is 5x, we could calculate the length of the bold arrow.

But given know of those we can't conclude anything.

Looking at the image, it'd be *my* interpretation that we are *given* the side is 5x and we are asked to determine the length of the bold arrow.

... which I'd do by noting:  $4x^2 + 3x^2 = 5x^2$ so triangle is right.

So area of triangle is $1/2*4x*3x = 6x^2$.  But area of triangle is $1/2*bold*5x = 6x^2$ so $bold = 12x/5$